# JQuery sortable with a handle - not possible to select text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, text, jquery-ui-sortable

When I use JQuery UI Sortable with a handlers (or without) there's no possibility to select a text from the rest of the element. I have tried "cancel" param with no result.

```
$('ul').sortable({
  distance: 15,
  items: '> li',
  handle: '> span'
}).disableSelection();
```

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/ikazuh/3/edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply remove `.disableSelection()` and it's fixed :)

You can select the text but not the handler.